# What is the time complexity of the second for-loop?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) { 
        //Code
    }
}
```

I know the first for-loop is O(n), but what about the second one?

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of your second loop is actually equal to 1+2+3+4... +n-1
Or :

```
  n-1
O( Σ )
  i=0
```

Why `-1`?
Becasue your for loops conditions are `<` and not `<=`
Try this out with this program :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                count++;
        std::cout << "n = "<< n << " : " << count << std::endl;
    }
    while (1); // Yeah, I know....
}
```

You can see that all results increments by the last value of `n`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For the given code,

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) { 
        //Code
    }
}
```

The outer loop executes O(n) times and if you consider the inner loop alone it gets executed O(i) times. The total number of times the code inside the inner loop gets executed is   1+2+3+...+n-2 = 
((n-2)*(n-1))/2 = (n<sup>2</sup>-3n+2)/2. Hence the complexity of the whole code is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Absolutly not ?